# Why is Paris/Idiorm not saving inserts?

Tags: php, idiorm

I have idiorm/paris installed in a Slim PHP API application. It is not throwing errors and works for basic selects, but I cannot get inserts/updates to work and am stuck with diagnostics.

Following table in postgresql:

```
CREATE TABLE distributors (
    id     integer,
    name    varchar(40)
);
```

Configure idiorm:

```
ORM::configure('pgsql:host=' . $config['dbserver'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname']);
ORM::configure('username', $config['dbuser']);
ORM::configure('password', $config['dbpass']);
ORM::configure('logging', $config['debug']);
```

This works:

```
ORM::for_table('users')->raw_query("INSERT INTO distributors (id,name) VALUES (2,'rich')")->find_many();
```

Create a model:

```
<?php
class Distributors extends Model {
}
```

This runs without error - but no record added to the db

```
 $person = Model::factory('Distributors')->create();
 $person->set('id', 3 );
 $person->set('name', 'rich');
 $person->save;
```

This, run immediately, returns null

```
 ORM::get_last_query()
```

Am using Paris 1.5.4, Slim 2.* and PHP 5.6.2.

Any thoughts on what is going on here, or pointers toward diagnostics? I am short on feedback from the otherwise wonderful looking Paris/Idiorm.

Comment: What does `var_dump($person);` give you?

Comment: Parentheses after `$person->save()`?

Comment: Don't I feel the idiot - you are right that it was the missing parenthisis.  Alttag do you want to put that as a proper answer so I can mark it as correct and give you the credit? (If not I will add it myself.. and make my humiliation complete).   Remain surprised that this just didn't work without any error or exception, but live and learn..

Answer (score 1):

With credit to alttag the error was simply a missing parentheses after ->save() - didn't throw an error or warning. Problem solved, thank you..

Comment: The reason this doesn't throw an error is because it looks to PHP as though you're accessing a property `save` on the class and not a function. Idiorm uses the `__get()` method underneath so it looks to PHP as though that property exists even if it doesn't.